# Angular 2: Show updated data

Tags: angular

When the user enters the page, the details of the item are showed. When the user clicks on the edit button: he can edit the category and name of the item. When he clicks on the submit button the updated items have to be displayed. How can I do that? And where should I run my postback to the database or something?

```
 <div [hidden]="edit">
            <ul>
                <li><b>Category: </b>{{item.category}}</li>
                <li><b>Name: </b>{{item.name}}</li>            
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="edit=true">Edit</button>
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="!edit">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ng-form-model]="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="bold">Category: </label>
                    <input ng-control="category">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="bold">Name: </label>
                    <input ng-control="name">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

private item:Item = new Item("food","apple");
    form = new ControlGroup({
        categorie: new Control(this.item.category),
        naam: new Control(this.item.name)
    });
    edit = false;

    onSubmit() {
        this.edit = false;
        alert("saved");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> When he clicks on the submit button the updated items have to be displayed. How can I do that?

Use ngModel (instead of ngFormModel) and bind as follows:

```
<input ngControl='category' [(ngModel)]='item.category'>
<input ngControl='name'     [(ngModel)]='item.name'>
```

> where should I run my postback to the database or something?

Data should come from a service.  Some component above your ShowEditComponent should get the data from the service, then pass an item into the ShowEditComponent as a bound property:

```
<show-edit [item]="item"></show-edit>
```

That same service should be notified when the data is updated.  I.e., your `onSubmit()` method should call some method on a service that can post the data to the server.  This means that your ShowEditComponent will need to inject the service in its constructor.